# What is the most efficient way to synchronize two time dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

| Time | Data1 | Time | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.1 | 1 | 0.2 | 1 |
| 0.2 | 1 | / | / |

And I would like to obtain this as a result:

| Time | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.1 | 1 | NaN |
| 0.2 | 1 | 1 |

What kind of code can i use to synchronize all dataframes?
I used several pandas functionbut they didn't worked, can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you first separate the DataFrame in the 2 different data frames with the corresponding Time and Data columns and then set the Time column as index for each dataframe and concatenate the both. This only works if the type of both Time columns is the same:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,:2].set_index(df.columns[0])
df2 = df.iloc[:,2:].set_index(df.columns[2])
df_sync = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(df_sync)

    Data1 Data2
0       0     0
0.1     1   NaN
0.2     1     1
/     NaN     /
```

The whole code:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = '''Time   Data1   Time    Data2
0   0   0   0
0.1     1   0.2     1
0.2     1   /   /
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), header=0, sep=r'\s+', skipinitialspace=True, engine='python', dtype='str')

df1 = df.iloc[:,:2].set_index(df.columns[0])
df2 = df.iloc[:,2:].set_index(df.columns[2])
df_sync = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)

print(df_sync)
```

Note that when I create the dataframe, I pass the argument `dtype='str'` to ensure that both Time columns are of type `str`

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, the time dataframe aren't the same and i want to synchronize them

Comment: @VESCLN I edited the answer answer to sync both dataframes